# Conditionally independent versions of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, independence

I have been going through some research papers related to information theory. Very often, I have come across this concept of independent versions and conditionally independent versions of a given random variable. I have some difficulty understanding this concept.

More precisely, say for a random variable $X$ and some measurable function $F$, $Z=F\left(X\right)$ be another random variable. What does it exactly mean when they say: "Let $X$ and $X'$ be two conditionally independent versions of $X$ given $Z$" ?

Though I understand what the above statement mathematically means, can anyone give me a more meaningful and intuitive interpretation of the above statement. Also I have the following doubt. How can we be sure that there exists such a version ?

Comment: I don't quite get why you assume that $Z$ is a function of $X$. Also the word "version" in the "two conditionally independent versions of..." looks strange (and Google agrees). Could you give more context or references?

Comment: @leonbloy: Here is the reference. http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0489. My doubt is regarding the Proposition 3.9 statement and a small note below that.

Comment: @AshokVardhan: This is just a guess: Could it be that two versions $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $X$ are called conditionally independent given $Z$ if $Z=F(X_1)=F(X_2)=F(X)$? Then, I guess, at least the relation $I(X_1;X_2)=H(Z)$ mentioned in your reference would hold...